# codeception: How to get custom config from BackendCest

Tags: codeception

I have an acceptance test as below and would like to get a (custom) config value (eg. admin_user: 'adminuser') from my acceptance.suite.yml file, how to do this?
acceptance/BackendCest.php:

```
class BackendCest {
   public function adminLoginTest() 
   {
   // How to get (custom) config value from acceptance.suite.yml file here?
   }
}
```

Any help appreciated,
G

Comment: I'm sorry. Don't get your purpose to get custom configuration in acceptance.suite.yml. If you want to reduce repetitive code (eg. Login) you may try using `StepObject`. http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode.

Comment: Hi @DharmaSaputra reason for the custom config is that I would like to specify backend (admin) login for my specific env in the acceptance.suite.yml (username + passw) to avoid hardcoding it (and putting it in source control) This way other team members can use their own login details in their own .yml files ... (each will be different for their specific environment)

Comment: IMHO. You are using it in wrong way. All test scenario should not depends on any environment. All credentrials should be hard coded in the scenario. Because we need it exactly to do what we expect, in specific situation. If you need to test different user case, then you should make test scenario for each user. To implement this, you may use database seeder. So you seed the database before each test run. In your case, so there are specific user exist in database match your scenario

Comment: Big advantage of implementation is you can push the test to run in test server, so it can run every time developers push their code.